# Showing error while back up the database in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am facing some error while i am trying to back up my database in sql server R2. 
it is showing the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore failed for Server 'Ironhide\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: You're trying to backup your database and you getting a restore error? I think you need to provide a lot more details here about what you are actually doing that copying and pasting a bunch of largely irrelevant text from an error dialog.

Comment: This is the error message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

Answer (score 0):

This i commonly a problem with how the database backup was taken, it looks like when the backup was created it was split into two files, you wont be able to restore it unless you have both those files. Try creating the backup again but when you do the backup insure that you only have one file in the destination section.

Comment: I only have the bkp file. Is there any other solution

Comment: Sometimes this is happen when you overwrite existing backup file with new backup file by the SQL server. Create the backup with new name or delete existing one.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been already asked in SO: [Any other solutions for SQL's “The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided.” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224745/any-other-solutions-for-sqls-the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are)

Anyway, your backup set was splitted in two files, but you're trying to restore the data from just only one backup file.

One solution is to backup your data in just one file and repeat the restore process. The other one is to provide both backup files and try to restore again the data. In this way, SQL Server won't warn you again with that error.

The Microsoft Project Manager for SQL Backup explains [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abf50e00-c9b0-4809-9e61-43ed8a53e968/the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are-provided?forum=sqltools) the error.