# Error restoring SQL Server 2008 bak file

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

I have took backup from one system and copied the file to another machine. Now I want to restore this database, but I get this error:

> Restore failed for Server 'sameer'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided.

Please help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any other solutions for SQL's "The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided." error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224745/any-other-solutions-for-sqls-the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are)

Comment: yes you can say.... but what is about these two files it needs i dont have any file.. i have only that backup file... is it possible to restore?

Comment: I don't think so. If you specified 2 files in the backup window then you need both of them. You'll probably need to create a new backup and define just 1 one file.

Comment: i have just uninstalled the sql server management studio.... i can not take backup again...

Comment: What do you want us to say? You can't restore. The duplicate answers this exact question. Is your question answered?

Comment: no it is not answered till now