# SQL Server 2008 finds database in .BAK, but SQL Server 2008 R2 does not

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, act

We received a `.bak` file as an export from an Act! database. My understanding is that this is a SQL Server backup that can be restored to SQL Server.

When I try to restore it to SQL Server 2008 Express (10.0.1600), I point to device: `path_to_backup.bak`. It immediately finds a database failed IFR_contacts, which is placed in the list of backup sets to restore. When I click Verify Backup Media, I receive the following error message:

> The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.2500.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 10.00.1600.

So I try to restore the file to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express (10.50.4000), but now when I point to the backup file, SQL Server doesn't find a database or a backup set to restore. I've tried in SQL Server 2012 Express, as well, with the same results as when I  use R2.

I understand the compatibility issue when I'm trying to open with SQL Server 2008, but I'm confused that 2008 R2 and 2012 don't even find a database in the file when 2008 is able to. Why would that be?

**Update**

Just to see what would happen, I downloaded and installed version 10.50.2500. It also does not a database or backup set to restore. Really confused as to how 10.00.1600 sees a later version that it can't open, but the later versions just don't see anything.

Comment: SQL Server can't restore a DB from a later version and, as you've discovered, it pukes immediately.  I would guess that the first thing RESTORE DATABASE looks at is the version of the file.  Since the file format is tagged with a future version, it gives up immediately.  Later versions get past this check.  I'd also [try using SQL instead of the SSMS UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119891/no-backupset-selected-to-be-restored-sql-server-2012) to do the restore.  There's several questions out there about "no backupset selected" problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why this worked. I was trying to restore the file from my Desktop. A colleague suggested moving it to the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\[instance]\MSSQL\Backup` directory. This directory apparently contains some magic that the Desktop is missing. Once the file was in the right spot, it opened right up.