# I am not able to restore backup file in mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a `.sql` database which is from a different computer to ms-sql 2012 version.

When I try restoring it, it says: "no backup selected to be restored". I tried setting the permissions, tried restoring using `restore tsql` statement, but nothing seems to be working. Both are the same version, 2012.

```
restore database tables from disk='E:\tables\Tables.bak'
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119891/no-backupset-selected-to-be-restored-sql-server-2012

Comment: i have checked it.does not work i am getting this errorMsg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The media family on device 'E:\tables\Tables.sql' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: "From a different computer". What version of SQL Server is the computer that made the backup running? If it's a version higher than 2012, there's no hope; backup formats can (and do!) change between major versions and backwards compatibility is sure to break.

Comment: a .sql file ? this is a sql dump of DB ? (sql script)

Comment: what i did was i opened sql file copy pasted in new query window of sql server