# No backupset selected to be restored SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have **already checked** ["No backupset selected to be restored" SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119891/no-backupset-selected-to-be-restored-sql-server-2012) but I didn't get what I was looking for.

SQl Server version: 2016
SSMS version: 14.0.17177.0

When I right click on a database and select *Tasks -> Restore -> Database*, the following window appears. 
[image]
And just after the window appears, the popup window freezes for some time and the error message comes on top of the window saying  "*No Backupset selected to be restored*".

Why is this error coming (since I know I just opened the window) and window freezing for few seconds?

I haven't initiated any restore process yet. It makes sense if I click on some Restore button without selecting a backup set (which I am not doing right now)

I was thinking this error is from Microsoft, but It has been present for years now, so maybe I am missing some settings !!

> Note: This error only comes on load of the screen, and screen freezes for some seconds. I can still continue restoring after screen UnFreeze again.

Comment: You have no chosen backup set, so you get the message 'No backup set selected to be restored'. What is wrong?

Comment: Yes @DenisRubashkin thats the thing. I have just opened the window to start the restore, but this message comes up when window shows up. I havent got chance to do anything yet with window

Comment: It is displaying that message because, like it says, you haven't selected a backup. I don't see you're point here. You need to select a back up, and (unsurprisingly) the message will go away.

Comment: If you had some backup set for your restored database, it would be chosen in the table in the down of the form. Obviously, before or after showing the window the process checks existed backup sets and then throws the error if it can't find anyone. You didn't select a database so its backup set wasn't found. The behavior looks right in my opinion.

Comment: @Larnu I tried to be clear in my question, but seems like it need more clarification. I know that I am doing have opened window to do restore, but WHY microsoft is telling me AS ERROR beforehand that NoBackupSetSelected. I know that as I ahvent done anything yet related to restore. Also window freezes for sometime. I want to remove this window freeze and error popping up automatically

Comment: It's not really an error, it's a warning/informational message.

Comment: As for the freeze, when you open the dialogue box, it needs to look at your back up catalog. If you have a lot of databases, and a lot of back ups in the catalog, it is likely processing that information, and becomes responsive once it's done.

Comment: I think you did non click on any database, you clicked at "Databases", then "Restore database". Otherwise the title window would show the name of the selected database (your picture shows "Restore database - " without db name) and also Destination is empty

Comment: @sepupic, No I havent reached at the point where I have to click on any database to select for restore. This error pops-up immediately when I open this window to initiate restore process. [Larnu] It is error message not Warning, since window uses Exclamation mark for Warnings.

Answer (score 2):

SQL server will also throw this error when the user does not have create database permission on the database. To check if this is the case, you can try to create a blank db or restore headers or other similar database command.

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY
FROM DISK='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.CIVILPRO\MSSQL\Backup\MyDb.bak'
```

Comment: Yes. I was able to create new database