# Cannot start SQL Server agent

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I re-installed w7 ultimate and installed Microsoft® SQL Server 2008 R2.

Firstly, it was problem of permissions, because I had error log like this

> User does not have permission to perform this action

That's why I tried this link:

[SQL Server 2008 R2 Express permissions -- cannot create database or modify users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185142/sql-server-2008-r2-express-permissions-cannot-create-database-or-modify-users)

I logged in as 'sa' and granted permissions to my users.

I restarted SQL Server, restarted computer but no news.

Just error log changed:

> This installation of SQL Server Agent is disabled.  The edition of SQL Server that installed this service does not support SQL Server Agent.

Any ideas?

Comment: The **Express** edition of SQL Server doesn't have / support SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have SQL Server Express edition which has SQL Server agent but `is and always will be in disabled state`. So you cannot start SQL Server agent on Express edition or Express with advanced services edition.

Reaon why it is present is becuase when you upgrade from express to Enterprise or Standard, SQL Server just have to chage code and enable it which makes the task much easier during upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable TCP/IP protocol with Sql Server Configuration Manager.
If with this does not work, try to grant access right to sql server agent user (sysadmin role or grant to acces to msdb database).