# How can I set the environment in VS2013 to create a DB compatible with the server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I get error like:

> "Impossible to open DB because the is version 782, but server supports only till 655 or earlier"

I can't overcome this problem, after 3 days!

Comment: it seems like if with the button Start, a 655 version of SQLServer (2008) is loaded, even if manually i start another like 2012 or 2014 with the following command:
SqlLocalDB.exe start v11.0
In that case i have 2 servers running but then I get error or incompatibily on DB

Comment: Mmm it seems I found the correct:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185142/sql-server-2008-r2-express-permissions-cannot-create-database-or-modify-users